# Joomla 1.0 to 2.5 upgrade, is it possible?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Joomla 1.0 to 2.5 upgrade, is it possible? I need to update my very old version Joomla site to a newer version but I haven't not found any article related to this issue.

Comment: It's possible even up to 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

You must migrate to 1.5 first, and then to 2.5

First follow steps in [Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable) to get to 1.5 version, and then follow steps in [Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5)

The procedure is not simple and there is a possibility of failure, in which case you have to manually troubleshoot what happend, so **do not** test it on a live website, but on a copy, and **always backup**

Comment: Hi @Marko,
Thanks for responding to me.. This upgrade process is feasible(1.0 to 1.5 to 2.5), or any chances for crashes..???

Comment: yes, there is a chance for failure, you should test the procedure on a copy of the website!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size and complexity of the site, it's very likely it would be easier to simply rebuild the site in 2.5. It's highly unlikely that you will be able to upgrade the extensions you are using in 1.0.x to 1.5 much less 2.5 and the template will certainly have to be completely overhauled as well. Unless the site is hundreds of pages, just rebuild it on a fresh install and save yourself the headache.

Comment: Hi, Brent Sound good for rebuild... :) my site's size not heavy, Light just few CMS pages presents, And I'm Already started rebuilt for 2.5..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible to migrate to joomla 2.5, but it is not just 1 click upgrade process. It is really complicated task. Because the 1.0 platform was not built for a seamless integration into later platforms, there are additional steps and processes need to be performed. Some of these steps, such as backing up existing data and bridging functionality gaps can be difficult.

Comment: I have explained this to you multiple times, now. You risk being flagged as a spammer if you continue to ignore my advice. Here is the message, yet again. Read it before posting *any more*, please. Please note that bare links to your own website/product are not encouraged here for two reasons; First, an answer should be posted as a self-contained answer, not a mere link to an external site. Second, self-promotion tends to be frowned upon here, and often is flagged as spam (especially if there is no disclosure that you are linking to your own site/product).